# Difference between Light DOM and Shadow DOM

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom

I stumbled a couple of times into this Light DOM thing but wasn't able to understand the difference with Shadow DOM. If someone out there could provide a clear answer it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The **Light DOM** is simply the *plain old* DOM tree inside a HTML element.

The term is only used in the context of web components to distinguish it from the Shadow DOM.
I suppose the normal DOM was redefined as *Light* in contrast with *Shadow*.

[The specs](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#shadow-trees) call it the *shadowroot host's node tree*, or *light tree*:

> A shadow root is always attached to another node tree through its host. A shadow tree is therefore never alone. The node tree of a shadow root’s host is sometimes referred to as the light tree.

I call it the normal DOM :-)

---

The **Shadow DOM** is the added DOM that *recovers*, *masks*, or *replaces* the normal DOM, as explained in the [article from Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom).

The rendered DOM can be a combination of the Shadow DOM and the Light DOM (through `<slot>` elements)

*Note*: it's not possible to completely polyfill the Shadow DOM behaviour in JavaScript, so Shadow DOM polyfills actually deal with normal DOM trees only.

Comment: The link shared of the Google article helps understanding the fundamentals.

Comment: well explained.
here in 2020, I find below web page explaining the above topics very nicely.

https://javascript.info/slots-composition
https://javascript.info/web-components

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668

Comment: The linked article, above, no longer works.  Here's an alternate article from Google devs:  https://web.dev/articles/shadowdom-v1

Answer (score 6):

You can say, the node tree that hosts the shadow root is referred as the light tree which might be **Light DOM** or another **Shadow DOM** as well.

Check this note in the [specification.](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#shadow-trees)

> A shadow tree’s corresponding light tree can be a shadow tree itself.