# Why does my shadow dom break my custom element?

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, shadow, custom-element

Here is a JSFiddle demonstration of the custom element: https://jsfiddle.net/c4bLo097/5/

Here is the code from the fiddle:

JavaScript:

```js
window.customElements.define('test-element', class TestElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
    super()

    let contents = `
      <style>
        :host {
          display: block;
        }
        :host([hidden]) {
          display: none;
        }
      </style>`

    // convert string to nodes
    let template = document.createElement('template')
    template.innerHTML = contents

    // create shadow
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})

    // insert nodes
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true))
  }
})
```

HTML:

```html
<test-element>
    This element should have a natural height.

    <div style="height: 300px;"></div>

    I should be able to see this text on a green background.
</test-element>
```

CSS:

```css
test-element {
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
}
```

If you inspect `<custom-element>` with your developer tools, you should see that the shadow is there. But my element will not render its height correctly.

Here is an example JSFiddle of what I'm trying to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/9483s1qb/2/

Comment: When you add shadowDOM the content of your element becomes "lightDOM".. no longer displayed and not part of your shadowDOM. You have to transfer it to shadowDOM yourself with code or SLOTs.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42093610/difference-between-light-dom-and-shadow-dom

Comment: I'm reading about the "light dom" now and you are right. Thank you

Comment: If my answer was correct, you you please mark so it does not appear in the unanswered list any longer. tnx

Answer (score 3):

When you add shadowDOM the content of your element becomes "lightDOM"..

It is **no longer displayed in the main DOM** and **not** part of your shadowDOM.

As [Supersharp explained in 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42093610/difference-between-light-dom-and-shadow-dom):

> The Light DOM is simply the plain old DOM tree inside a HTML element.
>
> The term is only used in context of Web Components (Custom Elements WITH Shadow DOM)
> I suppose the normal DOM was redefined as *Light* in contrast with *Shadow*.
>
> [The WHATWG specs](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#shadow-trees) call it the shadowroot host's **node tree**, or **light tree**:

> The Shadow DOM is the added DOM that recovers, masks, or replaces the normal DOM,
> as explained in [the article from Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom).

#### You have to transfer lightDOM content to shadowDOM yourself:

- with SLOTs:
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots
- **or** with code

```js
customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
    //create shadowDOM (thus creating lightDOM) and append Template
    super() /* return this */
        .attachShadow({mode: 'open'}) /* SETs and RETURNs this.shadowRoot */
        .append(document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content.cloneNode(true))
  }
  connectedCallback(){
    //append content from lightDOM
    this.shadowRoot.append(...this.querySelectorAll('DIV'));
  }
})
```

```css
my-element{
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<template id="MY-ELEMENT">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
      font-size:20px;
    }
    h4{
      background:yellow;
      margin: .5em 0;
    }
    div{
      background:lightcoral;
    }
  </style>
  <h4><slot name="title"></slot></h4>
</template>

<my-element>
  <!-- begin lightDOM because my-element has shadowDOM -->
  <span slot="title">whole SPAN is slotted</span>
  <div>I am appended</div>
  <div>appended too</div>
  <p>I remain (invisible) in lightDOM</p>
  <!-- end lightDOM -->
</my-element>

<my-element>
  <!-- begin lightDOM because my-element has shadowDOM -->
  <span slot="title">slotted too</span>
  <div>appended again</div>
  I remain (invisible) in lightDOM
  <!-- end lightDOM -->
</my-element>
```

**Snippet Notes:**

- The template is **cloned**
- the **append** in the `connectedCallback` **moves** the content,
  if you want to leave the original in lightDOM (eg. use it as a datastore)
  you have to clone it like done with the `template`.
- the `slot="title"` **reflects** the whole `span`(including the span!) to its slot in shadowDOM
  **See:** [::slotted CSS selector for nested children in shadowDOM slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61626493/slotted-css-selector-for-nested-children-in-shadowdom-slot/61631668#61631668)
- Do try yourself:
  In the JSFiddle playground: https://jsfiddle.net/CustomElementsExamples/bzvLcxfe/
- What happens with an **unnamed**: `<slot></slot>`?
- What happens if you change the `<span>` to a `<div>`